# Which ingested allergens can be transferred to a partner via bodily fluids?

Tags: allergies

Can some allergens, such as peanut traces, appear in bodily fluids (saliva, sweat, semen, vaginal secretion) after ingestion?

I would like to know in particular intake of which allergens should be avoided to prevent allergic reaction of a partner due to contact with bodily fluids.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on several factors: what's the biochemical nature of the allergen? Is it a protein? What's its size?

In short, the answer seems to be *yes*, to some particular cases. For instance, this paper deals with allergens from Brazil nuts transmited by the semen:

http://www.jiaci.org/issues/vol17issue03/10.pdf

According to the paper:

> We report the case of a 20-year-old woman with
>   documented Brazil nut allergy who developed widespread urticaria and mild dyspnea after intercourse with her boyfriend who had earlier
>   consumed Brazil nuts.

Of course, there is no general rule, and each case has to be individually analysed. This makes very hard, if not impossible, to answer your second question ("I would like to know in particular intake of which allergens should be avoided to prevent allergic reaction of a partner due to contact with bodily fluids"), because it depends on the case in question: the allergy, the allergen, the people involved etc.

This *Scientific American* blog post makes a good overview of the matter:

http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/food-matters/sexually-transmitted-food-allergens/